# Java - I'm trying to make a timer

Tags: java, timer

Can you tell me please why this code doesn't work? In my opinion it should work. It stops after is written in the console 1. I want to show consecutive seconds, but It works only if I comment `temp = passedTime` and then the script goes wrong

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Timer {

    private static long temp = 0;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

        for (int i=1; i<=1000000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            long pasedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - startTime;
            if (temp != passedTime) {
                temp = passedTime;
                System.out.println(pasedTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the code executes in under 2 seconds!? Try dividing the `currentTimeMillis` by `10` instead of by `1000` - you will see that your code works - it just happens finishes in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: I use BlueJ and if I comment the `temp = passedTime;` statement it shows repeated values up to 24. But now I've seen that I run it with Eclipse it works fine. I believe BlueJ's the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: i think i already know the answer but i just need to ask anyway : why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I just wanted to know how much time it takes to insert some values in that ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you an example for how to make a timer on a second thread, see here:

```
public class TimerAppExample {
    public static class Timer implements Runnable {
        private int timer = 5000;
        private long startTimer = 0;
        private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS");

        @Override
        public void run() {

            startTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Started timer at " + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(startTimer)));
            do {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("Timer event occurred after " + (newTime - startTimer) + " miliseconds at " + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(newTime)));
                    timer -= (newTime-startTimer);
                    startTimer = newTime;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while(timer > 0);
            System.out.println("stopped timer at " + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(startTimer)));
        }
    }


    private void execute() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Thread thread = new Thread(timer);
        System.out.println("Starting timer");
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Timer app ended");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerAppExample timerAppExample = new TimerAppExample();
        timerAppExample.execute();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting timer
Started timer at 2015-05-16 12:40:31:104
Timer event occurred after 1001 miliseconds at 2015-05-16 12:40:32:105
Timer event occurred after 1000 miliseconds at 2015-05-16 12:40:33:105
Timer event occurred after 1000 miliseconds at 2015-05-16 12:40:34:105
Timer event occurred after 1000 miliseconds at 2015-05-16 12:40:35:105
Timer event occurred after 1000 miliseconds at 2015-05-16 12:40:36:105
stopped timer at 2015-05-16 12:40:36:105
Timer app ended
```